# WebService Endpoint project built on Apache CXF is not deploying in JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf, jboss6.x

I have WebService Endpoint Project(Service Project) built on Apache CXF and which is working fine when I tested with Tomcat and VMware Fabric Server(comes with Spring STS IDE). I could able run WSDLs up and running. But when I deploy the same project in Jboss 6, I am getting the following Error. Looks like JBoss got its own Implementation of CXF. So how to resolve the issue??? Something Configuration change that needs to be made?

I tried this and didn't work either --> http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-JBoss

Error that I am getting :

```
17:25:25,829 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."my-ear-ws-endpoint.ear"."my-web-ws-endpoint-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."my-ear-ws-endpoint.ear"."my-web-ws-endpoint-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "my-web-ws-endpoint-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "afa-ear-ws-endpoint.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_13]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot publish wsdl to: C:\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\data\wsdl\afa-ear-ws-endpoint.ear\afa-web-ws-endpoint-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\SendACAFormSubmissionStatusDetailRequestService.wsdl
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher.publishWsdlFiles(WSDLFilePublisher.java:107)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.publishContractToFilesystem(EndpointImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:509)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:117)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:113)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Let me know if I am not clear with my Question

Comment: I assume you have read [this](https://community.jboss.org/thread/204976)?

Comment: Thanks for the Info @Perception So do you think its a bug when I got some XSD imports on my WSDL ?

Comment: Does anyone know about Whats the issue is?